# How to build table row(s) from ajax response (web service) JSON/JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am getting from web service based ajax response like the following lines.

```
{
"columnNames": {
"name": [
  "eredeti_szoveg",
  "text_bno"
]
},
"rowValues": [
{
  "value": [
    {
      "value": "adfa asfa"
    },
    {
      "value": "nincs info"
    }
  ]
}
],
"providedBy": "bno",
"id": "984f29fa-8743-4c9f-9b93-d307ed387f23"
}
```

I would like to create table according to ajax response (json), but my code shows only the full json:

```
{"name":["eredeti_szoveg","text_bno"]}
[{"value":[{"value":"adfa asfa"},{"value":"nincs info"}]}]
"bno"
"984f29fa-8743-4c9f-9b93-d307ed387f23"
```

I used this code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: wsUrl,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: soapRequest2,             
                                 success: function(data) {
                            $.each(data, function(name, value) {
                        $('body').append($('<div>', {
                    text: JSON.stringify(value)
    }));
});
$("#txtName").prop('disabled', false); 
                   $("#btnCallWebService").prop('disabled', false); 
},
                    error: processError,
                        processData: false,
                        beforeSend : function(req) {
         req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 
              'Basic c2NvcmluZzpzY29yaW5n');
                   $("#txtName").prop('disabled', true); 
                   $("#btnCallWebService").prop('disabled', true);  },
            })        
        });
```

The question is how to modify the above code that fits my requirement.

Comment: JSON.stringify(value) - you convert value into a string, I think this is why you see the stringified version of the response

Comment: @nagylzs: if I modify my code to 
 _text: value_

the result is

   [object Object]
[object Object]
bno
f3a97afb-cc02-4554-9b31-e46e39e48e60

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood the question. Can you provide a jsfiddle equivalent?